# how do i convert dropdown list all values into Million/Billion in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, for-loop

How do I convert all the output numbers on the dropdown generated by the code  like in these examples ?
(Ex:if the output number is 100 0000 I want to show this as 1M(million)
Ex2:if the output number is  1000 000 000 I want to show this as 1B(billion) )

```js
window.f = function(event) {
    var ddlArray = new Array();
    var onoffelem=event.target;
    var ddl = document.getElementById('ddl');
    var select = document.getElementById('combo2');
    var combo3 = document.getElementById('combo3');
    var selectedVal=onoffelem.options[onoffelem.selectedIndex].text ;

    if (selectedVal == "LKR") {
        document.getElementById("combo2").options.length = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < combo3.options.length; i++) {
            ddlArray[i] = combo3.options[i].value;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < ddlArray.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
            txt = document.createTextNode("Rs. " + ddlArray[i] * 185000000);
            option.appendChild(txt);
            option.setAttribute("value", ddlArray[i] * 185000000);
            select.insertBefore(option, select.lastChild);
        }
    } 

    if (selectedVal == "USD") {
        document.getElementById("combo2").options.length = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < combo3.options.length; i++) {
            ddlArray[i] = combo3.options[i].value;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < ddlArray.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
            txt = document.createTextNode(ddlArray[i] * 20000);
            option.appendChild(txt);
            option.setAttribute("value",ddlArray[i] * 20000);
            select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="ddl" onchange="f(event)" >
    <option value="185">USD</option>
    <option value="11">LKR</option>
    <option value="48">AED</option>
</select>
<select name="" id="combo2" >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="" id="combo3" hidden="">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `K/M/B`?

Comment: i want to convert long numbers into million / billion / thousand...

Comment: Can you provide an example input and what kind of output do you want from the input?

Comment: when im selecting the currency from first drop down.. i want to display currency conversation in second drop down.. &i want converted currency to be shown as billion/ million / thousand...because of my output numbers are too long thats why i wanted to convert long number into abbreviated string in javascript, with a special shortness requirement..

Comment: if i selected "LKR" from first drop down it will calculate with some numbers and give output like "180000000000".. and i want to show this output like 18Million / 18Billion likewise..also i want to covert dropdown's all values at once. plz help me to solve this. thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. Comments may or may not be shown initially, and are usually sorted by votes, not when they were posted. Make it easy to help you by putting all information in one place, the question. Please also explain: What is the problem with your current code? What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function similar to this one:

```
formatNumber(num) {
    if (num >= 1000000000) {
      return (num / 1000000000).toFixed().replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'B';
    }
    if (num >= 1000000) {
      return (num / 1000000).toFixed().replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'M';
    }
    if (num >= 1000) {
      return (num / 1000).toFixed().replace(/\.0$/, '') + 'K';
    }
}
```

Comment: You should call this function while setting the option label. Like this:  txt = document.createTextNode("Rs. " + formatNumber(ddlArray[i] * 185000000));